# Typescript / How to expect Fixed date?

Tags: typescript, testing, ts-jest

I am currently trying to test a fixed date. How can I customize my code so that I return a fixed date:

```
it.('reports fix date', async () => {

  aService.returnValue = [{ 
     activeFrom: '2020-04-19T10:01:58.135Z'
  }];

const somethingSpy = jest.spyOn(PubSub, 'topic');

await service.report([ 
 {
  activeFrom: addDays(new Date(), 30),
 }
]},
expect(somethingSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(

  expect.objectContaining({ 
      activeFrom: '2020-04-19T10:01:58.135Z'
  })    
)
```

Comment: I'm not up-to-date with jest, but this question doesn't seem well formed. What does the second snippet of code have to do with the first? Also where is the `spy` called, and how?

Comment: Sorry. I adjust my question. I hoppe u can understand what i mean!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a library like [`MockDate`](https://github.com/boblauer/MockDate) to override the `new Date()` constructor and replace it with a fixed value.

```
MockDate.set('2000-11-22');

new Date().toString() // "Tue Nov 21 2000 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)"
```

Comment: Should i leave it like that ```activeFrom: '2020-04-19T10:01:58.135Z'``` and Adjust the following like that?  ```activeFrom: '(new Date(2021-11-02).toString())' ```

Comment: I assume your system under test (the "real" code) has a dependency on `new Date()` and that your test code is having difficulty managing that, because each time you run your test your code produces a different result. Using a library like MockDate allows you to pin the date so you can write a stable test.